# React - CSS Transition like a book page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css, css-transitions, reactcsstransitiongroup

I diving in more advanced topics in my learning of React and Front Web Dev in general.

I learnt about `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` with leave/enter.. etc. But it's seem that it's not maintained anymore and we have to use `CSSTransitionGroup` now.

I made small little side project to try new stuff. I'm able to do a slide transition between two pages.

But now I want to spicy the thing more by doing a book page like transition by deforming the actual page and discovering the next one.

I'm looking around but didn't find a solution yet. I also started to read about WebGL or plain CSS3 Transition for this but I'm completely lost.

Can someone, not just gives a snippet, but also explain to me the approach to do this transition ?

Answer (score 1):

Transitions with CSS are pretty easy once you get the hang of them.

```
#myPage {
   transition: all .5s;
}
```

This little bit of css is going to say, if ever any styling changes on my `#myPage` div lets make it take .5 seconds to do that. Caveat with this is, it only works with countable property values. So `display:none` -> `display:block` won't make use of a transition effects. You would have to alter height/width.

```
#myPage {
    transition: width 2s, height 4s;
}
```

You can also target properties directly by naming them after the `transition` property.

Additionally you can use the `transform` property in css to manipulate elements in three dimension.

```
#myPage{
    transition: transform 1s;
}
#myPage:hover{
    transform: rotateX(150deg);
    transform: rotateY(150deg);
    transform: rotateZ(150deg);
}
```

Hopefully this helps get you started.

Comment: Thank you I will dig this. I know how to make a web app works back and front... but I have no clue how to make it pretty. By this I mean thinking AND doing good work about UI and UX. ;)